# How to download spatie/browsershot generated file into User/Downloads?

Tags: laravel-5, download

In laravel 5.8 app I use https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

and if I save file as

```
$save_to_file= 'file.pdf';
Browsershot::html(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content))
               ->showBackground()
               ->save($save_to_file);
```

it is downloaded and saved in /public dir of my app at my local OS

If I try to set path to ‘Downloads’ directory of my Kubuntu 18 as

```
$save_to_file= '/home/currentuser/Downloads/file.pdf';
Browsershot::html(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content))
               ->showBackground()
               ->save($save_to_file);
```

I got error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Process \ Exception \ ProcessFailedException
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"file:\/\/\/tmp\/0906513001561868598\/index.html","action":"pdf","options":{"path":"\/home\/serge\/Downloads\/file.pdf","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600},"displayHeaderFooter":false,"printBackground":true}}'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/public Output: ================ Error Output: ==============
```

1) If there is a way to download generated file into ‘Downloads’(OS independently) ?

2) I think that I can use php remove function but again how define ‘Downloads’(OS independently) directory ?

Comment: I asked pn spatie forum and got answer : >>> That's not a concern of this package. save just saves the file to the path you specify. You're responsible for the path you specify.
Can you advice some way /plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

I received the exact same error. No idea why I got that. Followed all the steps mentioned in the docs. Tried various resources still could not figure it out.

## Finally this worked

```php
$save_to_file= '/var/www/laravel/storage/app/file.pdf';
        Browsershot::url('https://www.google.com')
            ->noSandbox()->format('a4')->save($save_to_file);
```

The `->noSandbox()` was the key. Let me know if this works for you.